# 2020 US Open theme music

Tags: tennis, media, grand-slam

Before or after a match, there is a pop song that is played repeatedly on TV.

In the song, I hear a woman and chorus singing together. What is the name of this song? How do I find out about the different music they use every year at the US Open?

Comment: ESPNMusic has a twitter account (@ESPNMusic) which might be the easiest place to find this out; I can neither find an answer nor a Youtube clip of the music you're referring to (I can only find the clip they play at the start of the broadcast, which isn't it as there is no vocals).  Perhaps if you can find a Youtube clip you could post it?

Comment: And - there is the [ESPN Spotify playlist](https://open.spotify.com/user/espnmusic) which is a good source also to check.

Comment: @Joe Thanks a lot--I'll try looking on social media.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The song is "Kings and Queens" by Ava Max. It was released in 2020, and is featured before and after matches.

Comment: Nice!  Could you include how you figured it out, so others can perhaps follow your lead in the future?

Comment: I learned through the lyrics--just listening more closely helped.

Comment: Ah, thanks for clarifying!