# Song played in and out of commercial breaks for the 2020 US Open Women's Final

Tags: tennis, media, grand-slam

There was a song played in and out of the commercial breaks for the 2020 US Open Women's Final on ESPN. It's sung by a male and the lyrics are as follows:

> We'll be the last ones standing
> Be a light in the dark
> We're so long for this journey
> And we've come so far
> This is our moment
> Waited all our lives...

I can't find this song anywhere, and have been unable to locate it on YouTube, Soundhound, or by Googling the lyrics. I assume it's a fairly new song. Does anyone know who sings this and/or the name of the song?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because as it's about songs/music and not sports.

Comment: @alamoot Then you'll want to VtC [this one](https://sports.stackexchange.com/q/25134/15589) too.

Comment: @EddStockton Welcome to Sports.SE! Have you tried pasting the lyrics into a search engine? That always works for me, even on occasions where I'd heard the lyrics slightly wrong.

Comment: Yes, I have...and that usually works for me also. But so far, no luck. I always begin by using Soundhound, which is usually pretty good at finding even the most random songs...but again, no luck. Posting here was a last resort.

Comment: I think it's okay topic-wise; it's a reasonable question you might ask another sports fan.