# Song played before commercial breaks at the 2022 US Open

Tags: tennis, media

There is a song playing heading into the commercial breaks, that says "get up" and "electric". Does anyone know the name of the song or who sings it?

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is "Light up the Night" by Nick Connors. It was previously (mistakenly) suggested and then deleted on [a question about the 2020 US Open coverage](https://sports.stackexchange.com/q/25150/15589), and part of the chorus matches your description of the lyrics:

> Get in the flow
> Everybody move, get on the floor, yeah
> 'Coz we're so electric
> Feeling so electric

The song's YouTube comments also contain multiple references to the 2022 US Open: